# Get the field of a mongodb document from URL Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

I am trying to create an API route where I pass the field in a mongodb database from the URL and it seems to be that the field is not processed properly as I get no result even though the db has entries that match the query.

the url has the following format: `localhost:5000/api/animal/find/stripes/yes`
in a general form: `localhost:5000/api/animal/find/<FIELD>/<VALUE>`

The value is handled properly but the field not.

My code to execute the query is as follows:

```
exports.getAttributeController = (req, res) => {
const field = req.params.field;
console.log(field); //DEBUG
const value = req.params.value
console.log(value); //DEBUG
    Animal.find({
field: value
}).exec((err, animal) => {
    if (err || !animal) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'No Animals found'
        });
    }
    res.json(animal);
});
};
```

If I use `console.log`, I see that the correct values have been sent from the URL, and if I hardcode the `field` like this

```
 Animal.find({
'stripes': value
...
```

I get a result, only when I try to insert the `field` variable, I get no result. How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You want to evaluate the value of `field`, so instead you want

```
Animal.find({
  [field]: value // note the brackets that mean use the value of `field`
}).exec((err, animal) => {
```